# Why Xcode dynamic library can not compile only with header file,but static library can do

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

my SDK need another SDK, I have its .h file (xdjaalg.h).
When I compile my dynamic library only with xdjaalg.h file, error comes with:`ld: Undefined symbols:`. so I have to link xdjaalg.a, but I don't compile xdjaalg.a into my SDK.

when I change `Mach-O Type` to `Static Library` in `Build Settings` option, it goes well. But I want to use dynamic library.

Is there any way to make dynamic library just compile with header file like system framework do.

I am also curious that why system frameworks don't have this limits, I just import system header file like `UIKit.h`,it compiles well (no matter dynamic or static).but  xdjaalg.h build failed with `ld: Undefined symbols:`

Comment: Use cocoapods or SPM. They will make all configurations for you.